# TextureView/SurfaceTexture clear in Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-textureview

I've got a similar question like this one:

[How to clear SurfaceTexture after using it with a MediaPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355512/how-to-clear-surfacetexture-after-using-it-with-a-mediaplayer)

The only one answer under the above question is not acceptable in my case, I need a more appropriate way to clear **TextureView/SurfaceTexture** in a ListView so that when ListView reuses Views the last frame of the **TextureView/SurfaceTexture** will not interfere with the right one.

Desperately need for help on this, any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.